# Netlogo: Can turtles recognize lines?

Tags: netlogo

My environment contains a complex line drawn by a turtle.
Several other turtles are moving randomly. Can they somehow recongnize this line?
So for example I would like to ask these turtles to die if they cross or touch this line.

Comment: What do you mean by 'drawn'? For example, does the turtle change the patch colour or are you using links?

Comment: The contents of the drawing layer (I assume that's where the lines your turtles are drawing are made?) are invisible and inaccessible to turtles. The drawing layer exists strictly for visual effect; it cannot feed back into model behavior.

Comment: Are there any plan or possibility to make the drawing layer accessible? I think it would open some interesting possibilities.